# Django - TIME_ZONE and timezone.now()

Tags: python, django, django-timezone

I've the following settings:-

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'  
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Also, I've set `auto_now = True` in my `DateTimeField`'s. However, the datetime that gets saved in the column in of UTC (ie -5:30 hours).

I have set my system date as per the `Asia/Kolkata` timezone. Also,

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 13, 17, 40, 1, 505516)  # this is right
>>> timezone.now()
datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 13, 12, 10, 6, 496772, tzinfo=<UTC>)  # this is not what I expect.
```

Why is there a discrepency in `timezone.now()` even when `TIME_ZONE` is rightly set??

Comment: The very first sentence in the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/timezones/): "When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores datetime information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms."

Comment: Shall I set `USE_TZ` to `False`?

Comment: If you don't have any user with a location in a different time zone than your server, then yes - or simply delete that line as it defaults to False.

Answer (score 2):

`TIME_ZONE` is only used in the templates and forms etc. If USE_TZ is set to True (which is recommended) then the timezone.now() will always be set in UTC (time aware)
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE

"..... this is the default time zone that Django will use to display datetimes in templates and to interpret datetimes entered in forms."

This is why `{{ now|date:"G" }}` prints 16 (Moscow time) prints the Moscow time!

Another note is `timezone.now()` in a normally configured Django app will pick up whatever `TIME_ZONE` is set to in the settings ('America/New_York' in example below). But can be overridden as well (see below to Paris for example in a middleware or directly in a view for that request)

```
In [27]: timezone.localtime(timezone.now())

Out[27]: datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 23, 1, 53, 49, 793743, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' EST-1 day, 19:00:00 STD>)

In [29]: timezone.activate(pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris"))

In [30]: timezone.localtime(timezone.now())

Out[30]: datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 23, 7, 54, 19, 21898, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Paris' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
```